# How to get "raw" image data using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a base64 encoding of a PNG image (the string starts with `data:image/png;base64,`). My understanding is that this a base64 representation of the image encoded in PNG. Is there a way to get the "raw" pixel by pixel binary of the image using Node.js?

Comment: To be clear, you want to decode the base64 to binary, and then decode the PNG to individual pixel color values?

Comment: @Brad This is precisely what I want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. First remove "data:image/png;base64," from the string. i.e

```
const img = base64Data.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
```

Then convert the image from base64.

```
const imgBuf = Buffer.from(img, 'base64');
```

At this point we have the image in binary. We can then get the pixels. Try with this module https://github.com/scijs/get-pixels.

```
const getPixels = require("get-pixels");

getPixels(imgBuf, "image/png", function(err, pixels) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Bad image path")
        return
    }
    console.log("got pixels")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can acheive that by doing so:

```
var b64str;
var buf = new Buffer(b64str, 'base64');
```

As Buffer objects are used to represent a fixed-length sequence of bytes

Comment: I think this gives me a binary of the png image, but not the binary of the pixel by pixel values. I see now that I could have been clearer with what I was asking.